# Enable audit setting for a production site collection

Tags: 2007, administration, reports, site-collection, logging

Shall we recommand to have an audit settings enabled for a production site collection? if so, what are all the things that we have to consider before that?

what would be the maximum size of an auditData table per contentDB.

Note:
We'd enabled audit setting for our production web-application and ended up with an issue with DB as auditData table grown to 50GB, so wants to ensure that everything is considered before suggesting any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of auditdata depends entirely on how often your site is used and what your business deems as a suitable length of time to retain audit data.

Comment: please give me a brief description...

Comment: You'll have to set a benchmark as to how much data accumulates over a certain period, say a week. Then decide how long your business requires the data be kept, and work out your storage requirement for that..